# Limiting fluentd throughput

Tags: mysql, fluentd, throughput

## Background

I'm using fluentd to write into MySQL database.
Would like to protect the MySQL from being flooded.

## Question

How can I limit the rate at which fluentd is handling it's input?

Answer (score 0):

fluentd doesn't have a exact feature to limit throughput.

But, you can limit frequency of output by using `flush_interval`, and you can limit output chunk size by using `buffer_chunk_limit`. 
http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/buf_file

But, generally, streaming insert is not suitable for RDB.
Embulk might be useful for you.
https://github.com/embulk/embulk